# Anacron exit status 128

Tags: cron, git, anacron

I want to make a git commit every week, therefore i wanted to use anacron.

So I added the following line to my /etc/anacrontab

```
7       1       AGDienste.weekly /bin/sh /home/bjoern/Hockey/cronWeeklyAGDiensteGitCommit.sh
```

The content of cronWeeklyAGDiensteGitCommit.sh is

```
#!/bin/sh

cd /home/bjoern/Hockey/AGDienste

git add .
git commit --allow-empty -m "Weekly duties update `date +'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'`"
git push
```

Running this script by hand works absolutely fine. But trying to execute anacron using `sudo anacron -f` results in the following lines in `/var/log/syslog`

```
Sep 20 23:13:52 XPS-9370 anacron[7087]: Will run job `AGDienste.weekly' in 1 min.
Sep 20 23:13:52 XPS-9370 anacron[7087]: Will run job `cron.daily' in 5 min.
Sep 20 23:13:52 XPS-9370 anacron[7087]: Will run job `cron.weekly' in 10 min.
Sep 20 23:14:52 XPS-9370 anacron[7087]: Job `AGDienste.weekly' started
Sep 20 23:14:53 XPS-9370 anacron[7087]: Job `AGDienste.weekly' terminated (exit status: 128) (mailing output)
Sep 20 23:14:53 XPS-9370 anacron[7087]: Can't find sendmail at /usr/sbin/sendmail, not mailing output
```

Can someone help?

Comment: The error seems likely to be from one of your git commands - since you don't appear to have a mail agent, I'd suggest redirecting both your script's output and error streams to a file so you can examine any messages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found the problem.
The repo I push to is a github repo, so I need to provide an e-mail and a password. I already provided them and used `git config credential.helper store` as a normal user to save them.
But anacron must run as root, so it also needs the e-mail and password once. So I ran

```
sudo -s
/bin /sh /home/bjoern/Hockey/cronWeeklyAGDiensteGitCommit.sh
```

once and provided those by hand.
Now, `sudo anacron -f` works perfect.

Comment: Sadly it does not work with SSH authentication